# Calculate Pyton Enum each time when evaluated with datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, datetime, enums

Is there a way to create an `Enum` in Python that calculates the value each time the `Enum` attribute is accessed? Specifically, I'm trying to create an `Enum` class that stores values like `TODAY`, `TOMORROW`, etc. for a web app (in Django) that runs for many days and I want the value recalculated each time it's accessed in case the day changes. So, say, the app is launched on March 1, if the app makes the check for `TODAY` on March 3, it will return March 3 and not March 1 which is what it would be initialized for.

```
from enum import Enum
import datetime

class MyEnum(Enum):
    TODAY = datetime.datetime.now()
    TOMORROW = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Yes, but the main question is if you really want to do that, since it requires some meta-programming, and likely is not a good idea, but not that much for the technical part, but more because it means that a person sets `TODAY` in the database, but that will always be that specific timestamp when you *access* the choice of the attribute, so "`TOMORROW` will never come" :)

Comment: Likely this is the *X-Y problem*: you want to do something (named *X*), but instead of asking *X*, you think you will solve it by *Y*, and thus you ask *Y*, but *Y* might not be the best way to fix it. So is it possible to explain *what* problem you aim to fix?

Comment: It's for running a custom SQL query. I want to run it matching today, yesterday, tomorrow, etc, and it seemed like a good use of Enum. I know I can just use a function, which is what I'm currently doing, but thought I would ask to see if it was simpler or easier to use Enum. Sounds like it isn't?

Comment: Using a function that returns a tuple (today, tomorrow) sounds just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by programming a descriptor, like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from enum import Enum


class DtDiff:
    def __init__(self, delta=timedelta()):
        self.delta = delta

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return datetime.now() + self.delta


class MyEnum(Enum):
    TODAY = DtDiff()
    TOMORROW = DtDiff(timedelta(days=1))
```

But in this case this will even nullify most functionalities of the Enum, hence it is likely not a good idea.

Probably a better way is just define a function on the `Enum`, like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from enum import Enum


class MyEnum(Enum):
    TODAY = timedelta(0)
    TOMORROW = timedelta(days=1)

    @property
    def timestamp(self):
        return datetime.now() + self.value
```

You then can just get the timestamp with:

```
>>> MyEnum.TODAY.timestamp
datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 24, 19, 32, 41, 854253)
```

which looks like a minimal amount of work to get the timestamp for an enum choice.

Comment: I'm sticking with using a simple function, but I love both of these answers! Especially the descriptor one even if it does destroy most of the Enum function. These are exactly the answers I was looking for.